# Cannot run Protractor test cases on chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, protractor

I couldn't run protractor test cases on chrome and i have updated the vesrions of chrome,webdriver manager & protractor. Can anyone please help me out?

Versions are as follows:
Chromedriver : 2.42,
Protractor: 5.3.0,
Chrome : 67.0
web-driver manager: 12.0.6

Comment: Please provide more details. Did you succeed running it in Firefox? How does your _conf.js_ look like?

Comment: Yes, In firefox I'm getting results. But for some issue I want to run it on chrome. I checked for many solutions to run, they suggested me to update the versions. But still its not working.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be >= 68.0.3440.0..   But I'm not able to update google chrome

Comment: Trying to update chrome but showing JDK 8 is not installed, but java version is 1.8.0. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens when you execute `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: It shows webdriver manager is up-to date. Like I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.23.0 up to date.

Comment: It should also display something like `I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.42.exe up to date`.

Comment: Yes It is displaying and this even(selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
)

Comment: And your _conf.js_ contains something like `capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' }` ?

Comment: Did you also try `directConnect: true` configuration?

Comment: I have tried previously what u have said. But it didn't work. How to downgrade the chromedriver version? Any commands to downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Chromedriver 2.42 supports Chrome V68-70, that's why the error says `Chrome version must be >= 68`.

For Chome v67, you can use chromedriver 2.41 or 2.40. Compatible list can be found from [here](http://tps://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

You should install chromedriver 2.41 or 2.40 by following cmd:

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.41`

1) If you set `directConnect: true` in protractor conf.js, run test by
    `protractor conf.js`

2) If not set `directConnect: true`, but set `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`,

you need to start a selenium server instance in advance with specific chromedriver version by following cmd:
   `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.41`

If still can't work, delete other versions' chromedriver binaries manually.

Comment: I tried using those commands, but couldn't downgrade the chrome driver version. Is there any other commands to downgrade?

Comment: Please show the output of  executing cmd: `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.41`

Comment: Delete the had downloaded chromedriver_2.42, try again.